# Query table-per-month data without dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

A vendor, in their infinite wisdom, has decided to split a holidays dataset by month into separate tables i.e.

```
holidayPlanner.dbo.holiday_201802
holidayPlanner.dbo.holiday_201803
holidayPlanner.dbo.holiday_201804
holidayPlanner.dbo.holiday_201805
```

These tables are generated by the system as soon as an employee requests a holiday in the month. I can write a query that uses dynamic SQL to create a UNION query that I can work with.

Is there any way this can be done without dynamic SQL? Ideally, so I can create a table-valued-function to get the results?

Comment: Could you get them to create a view that merges the data together? Although that would require them to update that view as part of the process too.

Comment: I've suggested a DDL trigger that recreates a view using dynamic SQL based on data from sys.tables. I'm still hoping for a solution that doesn't need dynamic SQL.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an underlying table that holds it all with these tables being created ad-hoc or as Views themselves? If there isn't an underlying table this just seems like some of the worst database design that I've ever seen! It would require the process adding the holidays to have table creation permission, which in any walk off life is undesirable... perhaps find better vendors :-)

Comment: Infinite wisdom indeed. Unfortunately, I don't think that dynamic SQL can be avoided here.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a table function that returns as the result the values obtained in each of the tables to be identified (you could do a search by months)

I leave the following example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnHolidays]()
RETURNS @holidays TABLE 
(
    id int
)
AS 
BEGIN

    /* example data
    CREATE TABLE #holiday_201802 (id int)
    CREATE TABLE #holiday_201803 (id int)
    CREATE TABLE #holiday_201804 (id int)

    INSERT #holiday_201802 VALUES (1)
    INSERT #holiday_201803 VALUES (2)
    INSERT #holiday_201804 VALUES (3)
    */

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#holiday_201802') IS NOT NULL
        INSERT @holidays
        SELECT id FROM #holiday_201802
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#holiday_201803') IS NOT NULL
        INSERT @holidays
        SELECT id FROM #holiday_201803
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#holiday_201804') IS NOT NULL
        INSERT @holidays
        SELECT id FROM #holiday_201804
    RETURN;
END;

GO
```

Comment: That would protect against tables being dropped but that is never an issue, it would require the customer to manually adjust it each month.